# How to check if anyone is logged in with php?

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

this code returns true whether I logged in or not

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] != 1) {
    do_something();   
}
```

I wanna check if any user (session) is logged in or not

Comment: How are you setting the session when the user actually logs in?

Comment: You can't see the contents of other user's sessions so there is no direct way to do what you want. One alternative would be to store logins into a database, then you could query the database to determine which users are logged in.

Comment: Im not looking for (which user is logged in), I want to check if anyone is logged in

Comment: Your question is omitting the actual problem: cross domain issues. I’m betting that the first condition of your if statement is always true: there is no session key named LoggedIn. To prove the point, print_r($_SESSION) then die(‘contents of session ‘). You’ll probably only see the message from the die() command.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define, what logged-in means. Example:

```
LOGGED_IN = NOT_LOGGED_OUT && LAST_VISIT > time() - 15*60 # 15 minutes
```

Then you have to store the last visit time into a database table on each user activity:

```
UPDATE user_table SET last_visit = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE user_id=?
```

And now you can retrieve the number of logged_in users:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from user_table 
WHERE !logged_out && last_visit > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 15*60
```

Hope it is clear, that this is only a schematic solution.

Comment: Im trying to implement single sign on between 2 websites, I want to check if any one is not logged in then I redirect user to the main website login page

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] is a boolean.

So, you shouldn't use AND in this if, but OR. Something like this:

```
if (
     !isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])
     ||
     (int)$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] != 1
) {
     //not logged in
} else {
    //logged in
}
```